# How to find out if coordinate is within shape (.shp file) in python (maybe through pyshp package)?

Tags: python, shapefile, reverse-geocoding, pyshp

I'm trying to map coordinate data to a municipality. Reverse geocoders aren't as accurate as I need them to be, so I found a .shp that maps all the municipalities.

**I'm not familiar with .shp files, and was hoping someone familiar with it could help me understand the data it stores and how to read it with pyshp.**

What kind of information is stored in a .shp file? Would the municipality names be stored in the file/does anyone have experience using this package that could help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: You might want to search/ask over at https://gis.stackexchange.com/